# PrimeNg ConfirmDialog design messed up, CSS not applying

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui, angular2-forms, primeng

**Template :**

```
<p-confirmDialog  header="Confirmation" icon="fa fa-question-circle" appendTo="body" responsive="true"></p-confirmDialog>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="confirm()" >Save</button>
```

**Component:**

```
  confirm() {
    console.log('confirm?');
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
        message: 'Are you sure that you want to update?',
        accept: () => {
             console.log('update clicked');
        } 
    });    
}
```

Output display:

[image]

Is there any css file etc that I need to include?

**Template(full):**

```
<!---------------- Meta and Title ---------------->


<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Solid Waste Management System</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">




<div class="tables-basic" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#nav-spy" data-offset="300">


  <!-- -------------- Body Wrap  -------------- -->
  <div id="main">
    <p-confirmDialog header="Confirmation" icon="fa fa-question-circle" appendTo="body" responsive="true"></p-confirmDialog>
    <!-- -------------- Topbar -------------- -->
    <header id="topbar" class="alt">
      <div class="topbar-left">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
          <li class="breadcrumb-icon">
            <a href="#">
              <span class="fa fa-eye"></span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="breadcrumb-active">
            <a href="#">Organizational User</a>
          </li>

        </ol>
      </div>
      <div class="topbar-right">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="Edit.html">
          <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-dark btn-sm" href="UserList.html">
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Back
        </a>
      </div>

    </header>
    <!-- -------------- /Topbar -------------- -->

    <!-- -------------- Content -------------- -->
    <section id="content" class="table-layout animated fadeIn">

      <!-- -------------- Column Center -------------- -->
      <div class="chute chute-center">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="panel panel-visible p10">

              <div class="panel-body pn mn allcp-form theme-primary">
                <form id="form-order" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
                  <h6>OrgUser</h6>

                  <div class="section row ">


                  </div>
                  <!-- -------------- /section -------------- -->



                  <div class="section row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 ph10 mb5">
                      <label for="userid">User ID: </label>

                      <p-autoComplete (ngModelChange)="orguser.userid = $event" class="ui-autocomplete autocomplete" [suggestions]="results" (completeMethod)="search($event)"
                        (onSelect)="onSelect($event)" (onBlur)="onBlur($event.target.value)" field="userid"></p-autoComplete>
                      <input type="hidden" name="userid" [ngModel]="orguser?.userid">


                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 ph10 mb5">
                      <label for="perid">Personnel ID:</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" [ngModel]="orguser?.perid" (ngModelChange)="orguser.perid = $event" name="perid"
                        id="perid">
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="section row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 ph10 mb5">
                      <label for="Password">Password:</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" [ngModel]="orguser?.password" (ngModelChange)="orguser.password = $event" name="password"
                        id="password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 ph10 mb5">
                      <label for="fullname">Name:</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullname" disabled [ngModel]="orguser?.perfullname" (ngModelChange)="orguser.perfullname = $event"
                        id="fullname">
                    </div>
                  </div>



                  <div class="section row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 ph10 mb5">
                      <label for="type">CreatedOn:</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="createdon" disabled [ngModel]="orguser?.createdon" (ngModelChange)="orguser.createdon = $event"
                        id="createdon">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 ph10 mb5 ">
                      <label for="CreatedBy ">CreatedBy:</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="createdby" disabled [ngModel]="orguser?.createdby" (ngModelChange)="orguser.createdby = $event"
                        [(ngModel)]="orguser.createdby" id="createdby">

                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="section row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 ph10 mb5">
                      <label for="Deletedby">Deleted By:</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled name="Deletedby" id="Deletedby">

                      <div class="col-md-6 ph10 mb5">
                        <label for="isactive">IsActive:</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="isactive" [ngModel]="orguser?.isactive" (ngModelChange)="orguser.isactive = $event" name="isactive">
                      </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="section row">

                      <div class="col-md-6 ph10 mb5">
                        <label for="isdeleted">Is Deleted:</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="isdeleted" [ngModel]="orguser?.isdeleted" (ngModelChange)="orguser.isdeleted = $event" name="isdeleted">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- -------------- /section -------------- -->

                  <hr>

                  <!-- -------------- /section -------------- -->

                  <div class="section text-right mb10 ">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="confirm()">Save</button>

                  </div>
                  <!-- -------------- /Panel Body -------------- -->

                </form>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- -------------- /Column Center -------------- -->
    </section>
    <!-- -------------- /Content -------------- -->
  </div>


</div>
```

**Componenet(full):**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { orguser } from '../../Models/orguser';
import { PersonnelService } from '../../services/personnel.service';
import { OrguserService } from '../../services/orguser.service';
import {ConfirmDialogModule} from 'primeng/confirmdialog';
import {ConfirmationService} from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-orguseraddedit',
  templateUrl: './orguseraddedit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./orguseraddedit.component.css'],

})
export class OrguseraddeditComponent implements OnInit {
  orguser: orguser = new orguser();

  val: any;
  results: any[];

  constructor(private _PersonnelService: PersonnelService, private _OrguserService: OrguserService,private confirmationService: ConfirmationService) {

  }

  confirm() {
    console.log('confirm?');
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
        message: 'Are you sure that you want to update?',
        accept: () => {
             console.log('update clicked');
        } 
    });


}

confirm1() {
  this.confirmationService.confirm({
      message: 'Are you sure that you want to Add?',
      accept: () => {
           console.log('add clicked');
      },
     key:"add"
  });
}


  search(event) {
    this._OrguserService.GetOrgUsersForAutocomplete(event.query)
      .subscribe((userdata: any[]) => { this.results = userdata;console.log('xxxx'); console.log(this.results); }, (error) => {
        //this.statusMessage = 'Problem with service. Please try again.'
        console.error(error);
      });

  }
  handleDropdown(event) {
    console.log(event.query);
    //event.query = current value in input field
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //this.orguser=null;

  }

  onBlur(value){
    this._OrguserService.selectOrgUsersById(value)
      .subscribe((userdata: any[]) => { this.orguser = userdata[0]; }, (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
  onSelect(value) {
    this.getuser(value.userid);
  }

  getuser(value){
    this._OrguserService.selectOrgUsersById(value)
    .subscribe((userdata: any[]) => { this.orguser = userdata[0]; console.log(this.orguser); }, (error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }
  onSubmit(f) {


    this._OrguserService.addupdateOrguser(f.value)
    .subscribe((res: any) => {
      console.log(res);
    this.orguser = res;
      { console.log('success'); this.getuser(f.value.userid); };
    }, (error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });


  }

}
interface IAutoCompleteItem {
  value: any;
  text: string;
  markup?: string;
  isFocus?: boolean;
}
```

After removing all the stylesheet references and everything else on the template this is what I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Could you please share your code??

Comment: @RameshRajendran added

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you exactly wrong. But I'Ll give the proper way to use primeng confirm dialog box. You can get what you missing from that

First you need import `ConfirmationService` from primeng package

```
import {  ConfirmationService} from 'primeng/primeng';
```

Then you should inject this via constructor like

```
constructor(private confirmationService: ConfirmationService) { }
```

And use the below code while open confirmation dialog box

```
this.confirmationService.confirm({
            message: 'Are you sure to delete this?',
            icon: 'fa fa-question-circle',
            header: 'Delete Confirmation',
            accept: () => {
               // do accept criteria 
                }
            },
            reject: () => {
                //close the dialogue 
            }
        });
```

And the HTML code Could be

```
 <p-confirmDialog width="500"></p-confirmDialog>
```

### EDIT

> While looking your code, You are missing to assign any value for `Confirmation` object in `header="Confirmation"`.So please remove `header="Confirmation"` and add that in `confirmationservice` parameter. also remove `appendTo="body"`. Please try this and let me know

Comment: that is exactly what I am doing. Are you sure there isn't any primeng specific  css file that I need to import?

Comment: Could it be because I am using bootstrap on my page? Any possibilities of conflict?

Comment: @Arbaaz I have edited my answer. Please check it out

Comment: I am have removed my tag with yours ie. ` <p-confirmDialog width="500"></p-confirmDialog>` its still the same.

Comment: I think it has to do with the position of ` <p-confirmDialog width="500"></p-confirmDialog>` because as I change the location of this tag in my html , the popup also changes position and design

Comment: @Arbaaz Exactly what is i am thinking. May be some external styles are hiding the confirmation box. Could you please move the html tag code to top of the main div??

Comment: I have tried moving tag around and commenting style sheet references in style.css. Although I can see yes no button with `are you sure?` text but it is still lacking css. Are you sure we dont need to install/import any primeng specific stylesheets?

Comment: Please see my updated question I have added screenshot of what my confirm dialog looks like after removing all stylesheet references an other html elements.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have figured out what I was missing.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/primeng@4.1.0/resources/themes/omega/theme.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/primeng@4.1.0/resources/primeng.min.css" />
```

Since I am new to angular I am not sure about the correct way to reference the local files in `node_modules` so I have used cdn.

It working.

[image]